# PHP - How do I get the product name to the input form when the book button is clicked?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, input

I have a project I'm workin on, I'm trying to send data to an input form after a customer chooses a product from the list of products available. Each product has a book button, how do I get the product name to the input form when the book button is clicked?

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='book col-sm-2'>
            <img height='150px' width='150px' src='driverimages/" . $row['imagename'] . "'>
            <p>" . $row["fname"] . " " . $row["sname"] . "</p>
            <p> Age: " . $row['age'] . "</p>
            <button type='submit' name='sub'>book</button>
        </div>";
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $name = $row['fname'] . " " . $row['sname'];
}
```

```html
<input type="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>"><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want an action to occur when a user clicks on a button without page reload,  you should be using javascript or jquery. 
You should use javascript to get the value of the product name and insert in the input field.
If this action would take place on page reload for php to process, then you will have to send this through a form so that your php script can attach the user's selectionto a variable..

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip, I highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

...

```
<button name="sub" type="submit" value="<?php echo $row['fname']. ' ' . $row['sname']; ?>">book</button>
```

...

```
if (isset($_POST['sub'])){
    $name = $_POST['sub'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this but for the sake of your question which is obviously not precise enough, here is a quick solution:

```
<form>
<?php

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
?>
        <div class='book col-sm-2'>
            <img height='150px' width='150px' src='driverimages/<?=$row['imagename'] ?>'>
            <p><?=$row["fname"] ?> <?=$row["sname"] ?></p>
            <p> Age: <?=$row['age'] ?></p>
            <button type='submit' onclick="add_to_input(event)" name='sub' data-product="<?php echo $name ?>">book</button>
        </div>
<?php
    endwhile;

if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $name = $row['fname'] . " " . $row['sname'];
}
?>

<input id="name_holder" type="text" name="name" value=""><br><br>
</form> <!-- END FORM -->


<script type="text/javascript">
    function add_to_input(event){

        event.preventDefault(); // want form to submit ? remove this line

        var button = event.target;
        var booking_name = button.getAttribute('data-product');
        var input = document.getElementById('name_holder');
        input.value = booking_name; 
    }
</script>
```